# How do I configure Entity Framework to allow database-generate uuid for PostgreSQL (npgsql)?

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm updating our dotnet core project to use PostgreSQL on the backend instead of Microsoft SQL Server and hit a situation with two tables that use a GUID as the data type.

**ERROR**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Property CommentID on type is a database-generated uuid, which requires the PostgreSQL uuid-ossp extension. Add .HasPostgresExtension("uuid-ossp") to your context's OnModelCreating.
```

After a little googling I then realized I have to enable the uuid extension (not sure if this can be automated somehow) and then generated a uuid in pgAdmin successfully.

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
SELECT uuid_generate_v4();
```

Unfortunately my dotnet project is still complaining with the same error tho.  I see in the error it says to **add .HasPostgresExtension("uuid-ossp") to OnModelCreating** and I've tried in several spots but can't seem to figure out where specifically it should be added.

Comment: HasPostgresExtension() needs to be placed in your context's OnModelCreating, as the error says. If it doesn't please post the relevant portions of your context. Note that you must be using at least version 1.0.0-rc3-ci-39 from the Npgsql unstable feed for this to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per Shay's instruction - After updating to the latest version of Npgsql, the uuid extension error is now gone. Here's a snippet of what the OnModelCreating looks like for others trying this out:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.HasPostgresExtension("uuid-ossp");
    }
```